# Создание screenshot из html файла

Tags: html, windows, photoshop, скриншот

Смотрел https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URFhyvZTENc&list=PL3LQJkGQtzc6Nwz67GGrMdqxim1c0H5DC&index=2 с 13:00 по 13:40 и не понял в какой программе создается скриншот с 13:15 по 13:20 ?  Каким образом мне (на win 7) сделать скриншот из html файла index.html шаблона sparrow с сайта https://www.styleshout.com/free-templates/sparrow/ ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, скажите мне что я не один считаю это бредом, а не вопросом

Comment: Причём тут html файл. Мне прям интересно стало, что я даже видео открыл по ссылке. Там чел просто делает скриншот окна браузера. Я думал там для браузера плагин какой, который из стилей и хтмл делает слои для фш

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скрин на видео делается в программе Photoshop, но можно использовать обычный printscreen или ножницы.
Если надо сделать скриншот страницы https://www.styleshout.com/free-templates/sparrow/
, то можно сделать любый сервисом по созданию скринов https://pikwy.com/5f2c361a239d8231731cc00d
Если скрин не по формату, то можете пересоздать с нужными параметрами